# Audio fades out

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

I can find what is dropping my audio. I have my headphones audio at 100%, master volume 100%, the audio controls for the headphones at 100%, and the volume remains at a whisper.

If I change the volume on alsa  the volume will jump to what is shown then it lerps back to a whisper in 3 seconds. I can not find another setting that can just let me listen at the volume shown. I've looked through pulseAudio Manager and alsamixer, but neither have assisted in finding this mysterious drop in volume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that the headset I was using isn't fully supported by ubuntu. If I used the volume controls on the headset, then the volume was screwed until I restarted the computer.